# スプラッシュ画面が閉じた後に動画を自動再生させたい。

Tags: monaca, jquery

アプリ起動時の遷移として、
①スプラッシュ画面▶︎メニュー画面が普通だと思うのですが、
②スプラッシュ画面▶︎動画(サーバーにおいていあるmp4)▶︎メニュー画面の遷移を
検討しております。
動画再生時にはポップアップで動画を再生させたくて、どのサンプル(h‌​ttp://editors.ascii.jp/c-minamoto/jquery/003/等)を見ても一度ボタンをクリックさせてポップアップさせています。

②のような遷移にするにはどういった風にすれば良いでしょうか？
出来れば動画スキップも出来ればと思っております。

Comment: サンプルのサイトをiPhoneで閲覧してみましたが、ポップアップ再生されませんでした。

Comment: @ tutinocoさん　レス頂きましてありがとうございます！！すみません、このjqueryですとiosは私も確認出来ませんでした。別のを貼らせて頂きます。▶︎<http://editors.ascii.jp/c-minamoto/jquery/003/>

Comment: InAppBrowserを使うことは視野にありますか？それともページ遷移ごと動画ページを挟んでメニューページへ遷移させたい感じですか？

Answer (score 1):

iOSでインラインで動画を再生しているサイトやアプリを見たことが無かったので、そもそも実現可能なのか調べてみるとcordovaでは以下の設定を施すと、動画のインライン再生が可能になるようです。

config.xmlに以下追加

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
```

videoタグに以下のようにwebkit-playsinline属性を追加

```
<video src="sample.mp4" webkit-playsinline="1"></video>
```

後は先程のDEMOの`<img>`タグを上記の`<video>`タグに書き換えてあげれば動作するかもしれません。

Comment: @tutinocoさま　ご受頂きまして有り難うございます。すみません、あまり良くhtmlが分かっていないのですが、上はiosのconfig.xmlのname="AllowInlineMediaPlayback"のvalueの変更で、
下のvideoタグの方はindex.htmlのbodyに記入すれば宜しかったのでしょうか？
動画表示が確認出来ませんでした。

Comment: １つずつ段階を踏んで実現していくのが良いと思います。わからないことがあれば、わからないことを具体的に質問を再投稿してみてください。まずは、動画をインラインで再生可能か確認してみてください。それができなければ、そもそも動画をポップアップ再生させるのは不可能です。あとは僕より詳しい人の回答を待ちましょう^^

Comment: iPhoneやiPodではインライン再生は出来ません。iPadではインライン再生が可能です。その関係もあり、videoタグを使うのであれば`controls=true`がiPadでは必須です。(操作不能に陥るため)